# mysql ambiguous with PDO request using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

running the following statement in mysql / phpmyadmin is successful:

```
SELECT longitude,latitude FROM event JOIN location ON event.locationId=location.id WHERE 
event.id=1234
```

Running it with PDO in php 8.1 it says that "id" is ambiguous in the where clause..

```
SELECT longitude,latitude FROM event JOIN location ON event.locationId=location.id WHERE 
event.id=:event-id

$stmt->execute([':event-id' => 1234]);

Select failed: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Any ideas why it is not working with already fully qualified table names ?

Thanks in advance
Robert

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `-` as part of the PDO parameter placeholder.

PDO thinks the placeholder name is `:event` and the rest is part of the SQL - so if your event ID was `1234` the final query would end up as

```
SELECT longitude,latitude FROM event JOIN location ON event.locationId=location.id WHERE 
event.id=1234-id
```

i.e. it'll try to subtract the value of `id` from the value `1234` - and of course at that point `id` is ambiguous because it's unclear which table you're referring to.

You need to write something like.

```
SELECT longitude,latitude FROM event JOIN location ON event.locationId=location.id WHERE 
event.id=:eventID
```

and

```
$stmt->execute([':eventID' => 1234]);
```

Demo of problem: https://phpize.online/s/jp

Demo of fix: https://phpize.online/s/wp

Comment: Amazing, very good answer. I was expecting another error but after all it makes sense :)